# Reading discount rates

Tags: numbers

How I should read discount rates like the following:

> a $3.50 discount

I'm not sure if I should say

> "a three-fifty dollar discount,"
>
> "a three dollar and fifty cent discount,"
>
> or just "a three-fifty discount."

Comment: There's some useful Markdown formatting you can use to indent quotes, format lists, etc. on SE. I'd check it out :]

Comment: Just don't go overboard--too much formatting makes things harder to read

Comment: Also, I suspect you would benefit from joining the English Language Learners site.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/107238/14666

Answer (score 1):

The first one would never be correct. The second one is correct. The third one is acceptable, but not the best way of saying it.

Answer (score 1):

I think *a three dollar fifty discount* is the most common.

- *Dollar* is singular because it is modifying a noun.
- It's common to abbreviate *and fifty cents* to *fifty* after a dollar amount.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree.  Generally, the "three fifty" short form is use as an noun, not an adjective.  "The cost is three fifty," but usually "the three dollar and fifty cent cup of coffee."

Comment: I said *three **dollar** fifty discount*, not *three fifty discount*.

Comment: Indeed, you did!  :-)  I find the form "three dollar fifty" even less common than "three fifty" or "three dollars and fifty cents."

Comment: We must speak different dialects, then.

Answer (score 1):

The only correct reading in American English is "a three dollar and fifty cent discount."  The "and...cent" is virtually never dropped when the number is used adjectivally, as it is here.  (On the other hand, it is nearly always dropped when it is used as a noun:  "How much do I owe you?"  "Three fifty.")  I believe I have heard the British say something like "a three pound fifty discount," (missing the "and...pence"), but I defer to a native speaker across the pond on that one.