# Reading dollar amounts after "priced at"

Tags: numbers

I'd like to know the correct way to read dollar amounts after the expression "priced at."

If I want to read the sentence

> "This app is priced at $3.99."

would it typically be read as

> "This app is priced at three dollars and ninety-nine cents?"

I really want to use "dollars" and "cents" instead of saying something like "priced at three-ninety-nine."

Comment: Three dollars ninety-nine.

Comment: Neither the sentence structure nor grammar dictates how the expression is the pronounced. Practices vary. No canonical answer can be given.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I don't know if the pluralization is actually pronounced.

Answer (score 2):

> This app is priced at three dollars and ninety-nine cents.
>
> This app is priced at three dollars, ninety-nine cents.
>
> This app is priced at three dollars, ninety-nine.

While the first usage will be the most widely accepted, any of the above would be an acceptable reading. People who use dollar currency, of course, may drop the currency name and read it as simply

> This app is priced at three ninety-nine.

Incidentally, I'm not aware of anyone who represents the cents as a decimal for any of the major dollar currencies (i.e. never *three point nine nine dollars* or *three and ninety-nine hundredths dollars* or any such).

Comment: "three dollars, ninety-nine" is probably regional. That sounds odd to me in Ohio, USA

Answer (score 0):

You can say it either way; it's your choice.